# How to sort a collection of reservations

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Model looks like so:

```
    {
        time: String,
        date: Date,
        user_id: String
    },
```

return of end point get user reservations are like so

```
  "reservations": [
        {
            "_id": "63e3bda0a2b3be512b44ba51",
            "time": "10:40",
            "date": "2023-02-06T00:00:00.000Z",
            "user_id": "63d4657708205fda2de700f1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "63e3bda2a2b3be512b44ba56",
            "time": "11:00",
            "date": "2023-02-06T00:00:00.000Z",
            "user_id": "63d4657708205fda2de700f1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "63e3c22bf83f5954d210eb56",
            "time": "13:00",
            "date": "2023-02-06T00:00:00.000Z",
            "user_id": "63d4657708205fda2de700f1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "63e3c224f83f5954d210eb48",
            "time": "10:00",
            "date": "2023-02-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "user_id": "63d4657708205fda2de700f1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "63e3c228f83f5954d210eb4f",
            "time": "10:00",
            "date": "2023-02-16T00:00:00.000Z",
            "user_id": "63d4657708205fda2de700f1"
        }
    ]
```

**How do i sort these reservations based on date and then time. So the earliest date with the earliest time slot, and this done inn all dates.**

Can this be achieved with mongoose?

What i have tried:

```
    const dates = reservations.map((res) => res.date.toISOString());

    function onlyUnique(value: any, index: any, self: string | any[]) {
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }

    var distinctDates = dates.filter(onlyUnique);
```

First get all unique dates

```
    for (let i = 0; i < distinctDates.length; i++) {
        const date = new Date(distinctDates[i]);

        let distinctReservations: { _id: any; time: number; date: Date; user_id: string }[] = [];

        for (let j = 0; j < reservations.length; j++) {
            const reservation = reservations[j];

            if (reservation.date.toISOString() === date.toISOString()) {
                distinctReservations.push({
                    _id: reservation.id,
                    time: hhMMToMinutes(reservation.time),
                    date: reservation.date,
                    user_id: reservation.user_id
                });
            }
        }
        const sortedByMinutes = distinctReservations.sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time);

        sortedReservationsSlotToMinutes.push(sortedByMinutes);
    }

    const flated = sortedReservationsSlotToMinutes.flat(2);
    const sortedReservations = flated.map((res) => {
        let timeSlot = {
            hour: (res.time / 60).toFixed(),
            minute: ''
        };

        const minuteModule = res.time % 60;
        if (minuteModule) {
            timeSlot.minute = minuteModule.toString();
        } else {
            timeSlot.minute = '00';
        }

        return {
            _id: res._id,
            time: timeSlot.hour + ':' + timeSlot.minute,
            date: res.date,
            user_id: res.user_id
        };
    });
    return sortedReservations;
```

Then loop through all unique dates and find matching of reservations. Reservations is a param inn this function. Then convert their time to minutes, sort based on the smalest value, then push those reservations into an array. After that i then push all reservations sorted by minutes to an outer array then i flaten that array and return it.

Then i convert back the minutes to string.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a datetime using `$dateFromParts` and use the datetime for sorting.

```js
db.reservations.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dateTime": {
        "$dateFromParts": {
          "year": {
            $year: "$date"
          },
          "month": {
            $month: "$date"
          },
          "day": {
            $year: "$date"
          },
          "hour": {
            $toInt: {
              "$substrCP": [
                "$time",
                0,
                2
              ]
            }
          },
          "minute": {
            $toInt: {
              "$substrCP": [
                "$time",
                3,
                2
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      dateTime: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u7lhqdA2mbF)